# WatiN checking generated tables

Tags: c#, html, watin, dynamic-tables, browser-testing

I'm using WatiN to test a browser application.

When I press a button, a new table is added to the browser - it looks as follows:

```
<table border="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a></a>
            <a></a>
            <a></a>
            <!-- ... -->
            <a></a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a></a>
            <a></a>
            <a></a>
            <!-- More anchors -->
            <a></a>
        </td>
        <!-- More TDs -->
        <td>
            <a></a>
            <a></a>
            <a></a>
            <a></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I need to click a certain anchor in a certain cell.
In order to do that, I implemented the following function:

```
static void pressTableCell(IE browser,  string key1, string key2,int indeX,int indeY)
{
    Table tbl = browser.Table(Find.By(key1,key2));
    TableCell row = tbl.TableCells[indeY];
    int counter = 1;
    foreach (var Link in row.Elements) // I know it's weird to run with foreach and counter, but this is just for testing purposes, nobody will ever see this code except me, so i'm doing evil stuff. :)
    {
        if (counter == indeX)
        {
            Link.Click();
            return;
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

And I get back an exception - There's no table with the "border" property set to "0".

I doublechecked the names and everything.

Function call:

```
static void MakeItGlobal(IE browser)
{
    ...
    //Press the button that creates the table - works. I'm certain.
    pressTableCell(browser, "border", "0", 1, 2, 2);
    ...
}
```

My question is - Why do I get the exception? Doesn't WatiN know how to handle dynamic tables?

Comment: This feels like a race condition. Maybe JavaScript on the client finishes attaching the table to the document after WatiN tries to press the table cell? Can you give us a little more context about this particular test?

Comment: @GregBurghardt I see, gladly. Generally the site is an application they developped; it runs on many different languages. To change the language, a user needs to press the "Change language" menu button - once he does that, javascript shows a new table which appears with various different languages they can choose. Once they choose one, the whole site changes; What i'm trying to do is to change the language, and then click a button which does an operation on the site. In the end, I want to be able to press a few more buttons and then print the site's HTML.